# Format DateTime List to show only date and no time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a list method that gets the next 10 days in a list. The output of this list below is in the DateTime format of e.g. "28/07/2015 00:00:00"

```
List<DateTime> DateIntervals;
DateIntervals = GetTimeIntervals(
    DateTime.Today.AddDays(0),
    DateTime.Today.AddDays(10), 
    new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0));
```

How could I achieve the format "28/07/2015" with no time on the end? Would I need to convert it to a list string? What about if I wanted the time only e.g. hour and minute "17:15"?

Somthing like `DateIntervals.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");` will not work for this list

Comment: You should store whole `DateTime` objects in your model instead of strings. How you display them is up to you. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DateTime` doesn't *have* a format.  You *apply* a format when converting it to a string for displaying.

You *could* use Linq to project the list to a list of strings:

```
var strings = DateIntervals.Select(d => d.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
```

But this is typically done in the *display* layer rather than the model.

Comment: Another option is to use toShortDateString().  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: .ToShortTimeString() in this case, given OP only wants the hour and minutes

Comment: @sovemp Since the OP asked about multiple formats I assumed the actual format was irrelevant - the question pertains to converting a list of dates to a list of strings.

Comment: All these answers look like just what I was looking for, Thanks all!

Comment: @D Stanley.  I know what the question pertains to.  I am merely pointing out you can use ToShortDateString() instead, should you so wish. I do not disagree with your answer.  If I did, I would post it as an answer rather than a comment.  To make you happy: `var strings = DateIntervals.Select(d => d.ToShortDateString());`